# What is the sequence of this inline null check and addition evaluation

Tags: c#, null-coalescing-operator

I can't think of a better title, but this bug took me ages to find.

Can someone explain to me why this is giving me different outputs?

```
string may = "May";
string june = "June";
string july = "July";
Console.WriteLine(may?.Length ?? 0  + june?.Length ?? 0 + july?.Length ?? 0) ;
Console.WriteLine(may == null ? 0 : may.Length  + june == null ? 0 : june.Length + july == null ? 0 : july.Length) ;
Console.WriteLine( (may == null ? 0 : may.Length)  + (june == null ? 0 : june.Length) + (july == null ? 0 : july.Length)) ;
```

I have stepped through it and in my head I just can't figure out what the hell is going on.
What's the sequence of evaluation here?

I would expect the string null coalescing logic or ternary logic to be like so (which works btw!):

```
int tempRes = 0;

tempRes+=may == null ? 0 : may.Length;
tempRes+=june == null ? 0 : june.Length;
tempRes+=july == null ? 0 : july.Length;

Console.WriteLine(tempRes);
```

Comment: '+' has a higher precedence than '??'. See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/

Comment: @AlG Thanks for the link... should have thought of operator precedence!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's not so much sequence of evaluation as it is operator precedence.

> ```
> may?.Length ?? 0  + june?.Length ?? 0 + july?.Length ?? 0
> ```

This means:

```
may?.Length ?? (0  + june?.Length) ?? (0 + july?.Length) ?? 0
```

which is clearly not what you want. What you want can be expressed as

```
(may?.Length ?? 0) + (june?.Length ?? 0) + (july?.Length ?? 0)
```

Likewise,

> ```
> may == null ? 0 : may.Length  + june == null ? 0 : june.Length + july == null ? 0 : july.Length
> ```

means

```
may == null ? 0 : ((may.Length  + june) == null ? 0 : ((june.Length + july) == null ? 0 : july.Length))
```

Comment: Don't. it's not that intuitive. actually, it might be a good question to ask **why** does `+` precede `??`, when intuitively, you (well, I) would except the opposite.

Comment: Not sure what happened to my comment?! But @ZoharPeled I agree, I wouldn't mind knowing why that is, as well.

Comment: It's the comment monster. It eats random comments here and there, making the comments referencing them out of context... or maybe just a bug or a board moderator.

Comment: I haven't read the language design notes to know why this was decided to be the way it is. Perhaps consistency with `?:`, where in cases such as with `a ? b + c : d + e`, especially if `b + c` and `d + e` are on separate lines, it's more intuitive that you don't get `b + c + e`.